# Which mobile apps allow me to redeem a private key from a QR code?

Tags: private-key, import, mobile, qrcode

Which mobile apps will let me scan a QR code of a private key (such as the one created by BitAddress) and then spend the funds from that coin?

Please specify Android, iPhone (iOS), etc.

Comment: This can be more easily developed now thanks to an API offered by Blockchain.info:

 - http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=121297.msg1307934#msg1307934

Answer (score 1):

[Mt. Gox mobile](http://mtgoxlive.com/mobile), available from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mtgoxlive.trader) and on [jailbroken iPhones](http://apt.thebigboss.org/packagesfordev.php?name=Bitcoin%20by%20MtGox%20Mobile) using Cydia allows you to redeem private key QR codes into your Mt. Gox account.

As a bonus, if any payments are made to that address in the future, Mt. Gox will automatically sweep those funds as well.